# Insert FormulaArray whenever it finds a certain string of text

Tags: excel, vba

I have this list in column H.

[image]

here's my macro excel code

```
Sub TheSpaceBetween1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim insertRange As Range

    '~~> Chnage this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    '~~> Work with the relevant sheet
    With ws
        '~~> Get the last row of the desired column
        LRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Loop from last row up
        For i = LRow To 1 Step -1
            '~~> Check for the condition
            '~~> UCASE changes to Upper case
            '~~> TRIM removes unwanted space from before and after
            If UCase(Trim(.Range("H" & i).Value)) = "NOT THE SAME" Then
                '~~> Insert the rows
                Selection.FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF(C[-7]=RC[-7],C[-6]))" <----this is the problem
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

unfortunately, it's not working. it's suppose to replace the word NOT THE SAME with this formula

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF(C[-7]=RC[-7],C[-6]))"
```

what the macro does is

replace **ALL** the cells contents with the text NOT THE SAME with the formula `Selection.FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF(C[-7]=RC[-7],C[-6]))"`

can some help me to make the code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already Santhosh provided the right answer but i think he missed to add `(.FormulaArray)` in his answer .. Below one worked fine for me (TESTED)

```
Sub TheSpaceBetween1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim insertRange As Range

    '~~> Chnage this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    '~~> Work with the relevant sheet
    With ws
        '~~> Get the last row of the desired column
        LRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Loop from last row up
        For i = LRow To 1 Step -1
            '~~> Check for the condition
            '~~> UCASE changes to Upper case
            '~~> TRIM removes unwanted space from before and after
            If UCase(Trim(.Range("H" & i).Value)) = "NOT THE SAME" Then
                '~~> Insert the rows
                .Range("H" & i).FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF(C[-7]=RC[-7],C[-6]))"  ' <----this is the problem
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```